# Derivation of shifted Dirac Delta

Tags: dirac-delta

I have $x \cdot \partial_x \delta(x-y)$, and want to simplify it.
I believe it works like this: I use $x$ as a test-function and use integration by parts
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot \partial_x \delta(x-y) dx = \delta(x-y) x - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-y) dx $$

As x is anti-symmetric, the first part cancels, and we get

$$x \cdot \partial_x \delta(x-y)=-\delta(x-y)$$

Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a test function $\phi \in \mathcal D(\mathbb R)\def\R{\mathbb R}$ and your $T = x \cdot \partial_x(\tau_{y}\delta)$, we have$\def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}$
\begin{align*}
  \<\phi, T> &= \<\phi, x\tau_{y}\partial_x\delta>\\
    &= \<x\phi, \tau_{y}\partial_x\delta)>\\
    &= \<(x+y)\tau_{-y}\phi, \partial_x\delta>\\
    &= -\<\tau_{-y}\phi + (x+y)\tau_{-y}\phi', \delta>\\
    &= -\phi(y) - y\phi'(y)\\
    &= \<\phi, -\tau_{y}\delta + y\tau_y\partial_x\delta>
\end{align*}
So, in the your notation, we have
$$ x\cdot \partial_x\delta(x-y) = -\delta(x-y) + y\partial_x\delta(x-y) $$

---

Notation: $\tau_y$ denotes the shift by $y$, that is $\tau_y\phi(x) = \phi(x-y)$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me (or give a reference) about what your $\tau_y$ means?

Comment: @NicoDean Added.

Comment: Thanks. From line 4 to 5, shouldnt the second term also have a minus-sign (as the minus in line 4 is infront of the bracket)?

Comment: @NicoDean Thx, corrected.

Comment: and then also of course in the next line, and in the solution, right? (pretty sure, but not so sure to edit it ;) )

Comment: @NicoDean No. Note that $-\phi(y) = -\left<\phi, \tau_y\delta\right>$, but (by definition of the derivative for distributions, $-y\phi'(y) = \left<\phi, y\tau_y\partial_x\delta\right>$.

Comment: Do you know some good references for the way how you deal with Dirac-Deltas? I learned it only by applying it to Test-Functions in integrals, but it seems that your notation is more useful.

Comment: Any book on "distribtion theory" should do that ...