# Derivative of Dirac Delta with nested function

Tags: distribution-theory

A similar question has already been asked here: [Derivation of Dirac-Delta with complicated argument $\delta(f(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/863125/derivation-of-dirac-delta-with-complicated-argument-deltafx)

But now I want to do the following. Given the Hamiltonian $H=H(q(t),p(t),t)=E$ is a constant we can define its phase space volume as:
$$\int \delta(H(q(t),p(t),t)-E)dqdp$$
How can one evaluate the rate of change of the phase space volume, considering that q and p are functions of time?
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int \delta(H(q(t),p(t),t)-E)dqdp$$

Comment: What is the range of the integral?

Comment: all of real space

Comment: Then, unless I'm missing something, I don't think the integral makes sense as stated. For me, $x=x(t), y=y(t)$ says that $(x,y)$ defines a unique curve parametrized by $t\in \mathbb{R}$, while $\int ... dx(t) dy(t)$ says that $(x,y)$ varies over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But both aren't possible at the same time. For example, what would be $\int e^{-(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)} dx(t) dy(t)$ if $x(t)=y(t)=t$?

If $\int ... dx(t) dy(t)$ means integrating over all possible curves (like in a path integral) then the integral makes sense but the output doesn't depend on $t$ so the derivative is 0.

Comment: let me edit the question so it makes more sense (please see above)

Comment: Take a look at the co-area formula.

Comment: thanks. my guess is that that will help. I have a question thought. which area of mathematics deals with these kind of manipulations? is it functional analysis?

Comment: Distribution theory and geometric measure theory. Functional analysis is related, though.